# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type IRepository while attempting to activate UserSevice

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I created an .NET Core 2.0 MVC application and use Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern to inject a repository to my controller. However, I am 
getting an error when my UserService is going to inject in UserController:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'FFLEX.Services.Repository.IGenericRepository`1[FFLEX.Core.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'FFLEX.Services.User.UserService'.

**GenericRepository**

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {
    protected ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsyn() {
        return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**IUserService**

```
public interface IUserService {
    Task<ICollection<ApplicationUser>> GetAllNonSuperAdminUsers();
}
```

**UserService**

```
public class UserService : IUserService {
    protected readonly IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser> _repository;

    public UserService(IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser> repository) {
        repository = repository;
   }

    public async Task<ICollection<ApplicationUser>> GetAllNonSuperAdminUsers() {
        return await _repository.GetAllAsyn();
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
public class UserController : Controller {
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService) {
        userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
        var test = await PrepareUserViewModel();
        return View(test);
    }

    public async Task<UserViewModel> PrepareUserViewModel() {
        UserViewModel vm = new UserViewModel();
        vm.UserCount = 1;
        vm.Subscribers = 1;
        vm.Guest = 1;
        vm.Users = await _userService.GetAllNonSuperAdminUsers();
        return vm;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs Configurations**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(FFLEXConsts.ConnectionString));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    //services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help me out of it because it seems that there is not any issue in it.

Comment: I do not see you register a `IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser>`, from the error it seems the injector cannot resolve it. Any reason you don't regsiter it in the `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: You are missing `services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<ApplicationUser>, GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>>();` from your `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: @CalC Thanks alot it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just forgot to add `services.AddScoped<Internface,class>` to my `startup.cs` class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Entity Framework Core database first approach. I followed the below steps and resolved the error.

**Step 1:** Check that your context class constructor looks like this

```cs
public partial class ZPHSContext : DbContext
{
    public ZPHSContext(DbContextOptions<ZPHSContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** In the Startup.cs file register your context class

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<ZPHSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

**Step 3:** Add the connection string in appsettings.json

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=Server=****;Database=ZPHSS;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

**Step 4:** Remove the default code from the `OnConfiguring` method in the context class

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
}
```